# Load image with alpha transparency onto a userform from a filepath

Tags: vba, image, excel, transparency, userform

I would like to place an image into a VBA UserForm image control, and preserve its transparency (either 1-bit on-off transparency like an ico file has, or better; full alpha channel transparency like a png can have).

That is, portions of the image which are transparent in the original file are also see-through on my userform, so I can overlay images for example.

---

First of all, I couldn't find an answer on SO, so I had to look on *other* forums. I found 1 method which supports 1-bit on/off transparency, I'll post it as an answer so now it can be found more easily here.

But the method I've found loads pictures from the clipboard, meaning to load from a filepath I have to

```
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("[filepath]").Cut
myUserform.someImageControl.Picture = PastePicture
```

Which seems slow and convoluted, and also wipes the clipboard, so I'm wondering if there's a good way to load transparent pictures to a userform from a filepath (without using clipboard)?

---

The second point is that the current code I have looks awful (the results that is, although the code itself is a bit messy). To get better results, I'm surprised there's not some framework I can reference which returns an `IPictureDisp` with transparency.

The *Windows Image Aquisition Library v2.0* (`wiaaut.dll`) can be used to load pngs to a control - e.g.

```
Function loadImg(fileLocation As String) As IPictureDisp
Dim imgctrl As New WIA.ImageFile         'can handle more extensions than built in LoadPicture function
With imgctrl
    .LoadFile fileLocation
    Set loadImg = .fileData.Picture
End With
Set imgctrl = Nothing
End Function
```

However it removes the transparency which is no good. So I'm asking this question to pool resources on what alternate methods people are aware of (if any), and which provide the best results?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, in case there isn't a copy on SO somewhere else: here is a function which can be used in place of LoadPicture to apply an image to an Image Control on a userform. It supports 1 bit transparency only (I.e. pixel is visible or it isn't)

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

''' User-Defined Types for API Calls

'Declare a UDT to store a GUID for the IPicture OLE Interface
Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

'Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
Private Type uPicDesc
    Size As Long
    Type As Long
    hPic As Long
    hPal As Long
End Type

'''Windows API Function Declarations

'Does the clipboard contain a bitmap/metafile?
Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" ( _
                         ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

'Open the clipboard to read
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" ( _
                         ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

'Get a pointer to the bitmap/metafile
Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" ( _
                         ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

'Close the clipboard
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

'Convert the handle into an OLE IPicture interface.
Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32.dll" ( _
                         PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, _
                         ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long

'Create our own copy of the metafile, so it doesn't get _
'wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
Declare Function CopyEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias "CopyEnhMetaFileA" ( _
        ByVal hemfSrc As Long, ByVal lpszFile As String) As Long

'Create our own copy of the bitmap, so it doesn't get wiped out by
'subsequent
'clipboard updates.
Declare Function CopyImage Lib "user32" (ByVal handle As Long, _
                                         ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, _
                                         ByVal un2 As Long) As Long

'The API format types we're interested in
Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Const IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
Const LR_COPYRETURNORG = &H4

Function PastePicture(Optional lXlPicType As Long = xlPicture) As IPicture
    'Some pointers
    Dim h As Long, hPicAvail As Long, hPtr As Long, hPal As Long
    Dim lPicType As Long, hCopy As Long

    'Convert xl piture-type constant to the API constant equivalent
    lPicType = IIf(lXlPicType = xlBitmap, CF_BITMAP, CF_ENHMETAFILE)

    'Check if the clipboard contains the required format
    hPicAvail = IsClipboardFormatAvailable(lPicType)

    If hPicAvail <> 0 Then
        'Get access to the clipboard
        h = OpenClipboard(0&)

        If h > 0 Then
            'Get a handle to the image data
            hPtr = GetClipboardData(lPicType)

            'Create our own copy of the image on the clipboard, in the appropriate format.
            If lPicType = CF_BITMAP Then
                hCopy = CopyImage(hPtr, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_COPYRETURNORG)
            Else
                hCopy = CopyEnhMetaFile(hPtr, vbNullString)
            End If

            'Release the clipboard to other programs
            h = CloseClipboard

            'If we got a handle to the image, convert it into a Picture object and return it
            If hPtr <> 0 Then Set PastePicture = CreatePicture(hCopy, 0, lPicType)
        End If
    End If

End Function

Private Function CreatePicture(ByVal hPic As Long, ByVal hPal As Long, _
                               ByVal lPicType) As IPicture

    ' IPicture requires a reference to "OLE Automation"
    Dim r As Long, uPicInfo As uPicDesc, IID_IDispatch As GUID, IPic As IPicture

    'OLE Picture types
    Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1
    Const PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE = 4

    ' Create the Interface GUID (for the IPicture interface)
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H7BF80980
        .Data2 = &HBF32
        .Data3 = &H101A
        .Data4(0) = &H8B
        .Data4(1) = &HBB
        .Data4(2) = &H0
        .Data4(3) = &HAA
        .Data4(4) = &H0
        .Data4(5) = &H30
        .Data4(6) = &HC
        .Data4(7) = &HAB
    End With

    ' Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
    With uPicInfo
        .Size = Len(uPicInfo)
        .Type = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, PICTYPE_BITMAP, PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE)
        .hPic = hPic
        .hPal = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, hPal, 0)
    End With

    ' Create the Picture object.
    r = OleCreatePictureIndirect(uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic)

    ' If an error occured, show the description
    If r <> 0 Then
        'Debug.Print "Create Picture: " & fnOLEError(r)
Debug.Print "Error, call fnOLEError(r) here"
        ' fnOLEError from modPastePicture not posted
    End If

    ' Return the new Picture object.
    Set CreatePicture = IPic

End Function
```

[Source with minor edits](https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/putting-a-picture-onto-a-userform-without-using-the-vba-window.3930506/)

[Original source](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/excel/) is Stephen Bullen's pastePicture.zip

use like:

```
Set myImageControl.Picture = PastePicture
```