# How to display PNG images with transparent background in an Excel VBA UserForm

Tags: vba, background, png, transparency, userform

I am using VBA in Excel to make an UserForm. I would like to display in this UserForm an image with transparent background that is in PNG format.
Initially I was getting an error message because VBA does not support PNG format natively, so I found out that if I reference Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0 and use the following code, VBA is able to display the PNG image in an ImageControl.

```
Sub ShowForm()
    UserForm1.Image1.Picture = loadImg("C:\Temp\Logo.png")
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Function loadImg(fileLocation As String) As IPictureDisp
Dim imgctrl As New WIA.ImageFile         'can handle more extensions than built in LoadPicture function
With imgctrl
    .LoadFile fileLocation
    Set loadImg = .fileData.Picture
End With
Set imgctrl = Nothing
End Function
```

The problem I am experiencing now is that the image is showed but the background is not transparent. Does somebody could help me to solve this issue?
An additional doubt I have is if would be possible embed image in Excel instead of call it from a path, as was done in loadImg function.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just make the image background the same color as the form? Why do you need it to be transparent?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847205/load-image-with-alpha-transparency-onto-a-userform-from-a-filepath

Comment: Thanks, Tim! It works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while, but here we go: Save your image (in Photoshop, for example) in ".gif". Then, in Excel / userform, insert image. In the window, choose "all files" and "image.gif" will appear. It only loses its quality a little compared to ".png"

Answer (score 0):

Complementing @fernando F, once in Photoshop: Save as image.gif > In "Indexed Colours" select Palette "Web" > mark "Transparency" > OK. Once in VBA Userform, open your Image1 properties, select BackStyle and set to "0-FrmBackStyleTransparent"